# Why symbol-value throws a void-variable error with a let form if lexical binding is on?

Tags: lexical-binding

Here's a simple example from the manual:

```
;; Here the symbol ‘abracadabra’
;;   is the symbol whose value is examined.
(let ((abracadabra 'foo))
  (symbol-value 'abracadabra))
⇒ foo
```

Why does this throw an error with lexical binding? The variable is bound in the let, isn't it?

Emacs 26.2

Comment: Which is to say (and unlike dynamic variables), lexical values are *not* stored in the value slot of the associated symbol.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The manual also describes this, but in a way that skimming over it I thought if the variable has no lexical value then it falls back to the dynamically bound value.